# why does the first alternation not match?

Tags: python, regex, regex-alternation

I have the [following regular expression](https://www.regex101.com/r/tG8zR7/1) (Python) that I don't understand at the following point. Why doesn't it match the first alternation, too?

**Regex (spaced for better understanding):**

```
(?:
  \$\{
    (?P<braced>
       [_a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?::[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*)+
    )
  \}
)
|   ### SECOND ALTERNATION ###
(?:
  \$
   (?P<named>
     [_a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?::[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*)+
   )
)
```

**Test String:**

asdasd $asd:sd + ${asd123:asd} $HOME $$asd

**Matched stuff:**

asdasd **$asd:sd** + ${asd123:asd} $HOME $$asd

According to the regex pattern above, the first alternation should also appear, namely:

```
${asd123:asd}
```

It seems I don't quite get the alternation pattern?

Comment: Do you mean you want to capture `${...}`, too? Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/uR4hJ9/1. You have non-capturing groups `(?:)`, when you remove the `?:`, you will turn on capturing.

Comment: yes, please :-), thanks :-) lets see whats different

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not yet : I dont get the difference, it seems that only newlines changes the syntax? and you removed the (?:  -> non-capturing group?
I would like to understand it

Comment: There is a good post on non-capturing groups: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group

Comment: where is the difference, to yours, its the same but it does not match?:
https://www.regex101.com/r/eL1lH0/1

Comment: I posted my answer. Please read the information about non-capturing groups at regular-expressions.info, the main point is that we can make capturing groups optional with non-capturing groups. Making them capturing, we can extract/find/match data we need.

Comment: @Gabriel: The difference is the flag `x` which allows free-spacing so that you can format your regex. I don't think there is a need to remove the capturing group, since it seems that the point of the regex is to ignore the `$` and the surrounding `${}`.

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. Are you also having trouble getting all matches in python or just problems with the display on the website?

Comment: yes, i still have trouble matching the following in python, I thought of asking about a stupid regex is a too stupid question, so I posted this question whose answer is straight forward simple.
the related question i posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053885/custom-python-template-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to capture `${...}`, you need to remove `?:` to turn *non-capturing* groups into *capturing* ones. You can make them named as well. Also **[_a-zA-Z0-9]** is equal to **\w**, thus we can shorten your regex a bit:

```
(?P<Alternation1>
 \$\{(?P<braced>[_a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?::[_a-zA-Z]\w*)+)
 \}
 )
 |
 (?P<Alternation2>
  \$(?P<named>[_a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?::[_a-zA-Z]\w*)+
 )
)
```

Have a look at the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uR4hJ9/3). This regex requires the use of `x` option (and `g` options on regex101.com to show all matches, in Python, you'd use `findall` or `finditer`).

More information about [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group) is available on SO and at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

To just get all matches in Python, you can use `finditer` like this:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'''(?P<Alternation1>
     \$\{(?P<braced>[_a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?::[_a-zA-Z]\w*)+)
     \}
     )
     |
     (?P<Alternation2>
      \$(?P<named>[_a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?::[_a-zA-Z]\w*)+
     )
    )
''', re.VERBOSE)
test_str = u"asdasd $asd:sd + ${asd123:asd} $HOME $$asd"

print [x for x in re.findall(p, test_str)]
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/4oWguB)

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern works well, all you need is to use it with `finditer` to perform a global research and obtain the whole match:

```
>>> for m in re.finditer(pattern, text):
...     print 'whole match: %s' (m.group(0))
...     print 'group "braced": %s' % (m.group('braced'))
...     print 'group "named": %s\n' % (m.group('named'))
```

(The problem with `findall` *(that performs a global research too)* is that when you have capture groups in the pattern, the result contains only a list of capture groups contents and no more the whole match result. So enclosing all in a capture group as suggested by stribizhev can be a way with `findall`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `g` modifier to get all matches on regex101.com

https://www.regex101.com/r/nP8pK0/1

Comment: Maybe that's how it works in other languages, but Python's regex syntax doesn't work that way.

Comment: You are correct, there is no `g` modifier in Python regular expressions, because we use `findall` to get all matches. OP's question is about not getting a match on regex101.com site

Comment: This is only good for demonstration at regex101, no actual use in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was basically interessted how  to match the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053885/custom-python-template-string